# Adding a jquery click function to a disabled button?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can I do this?

I have a disabled jquery ui button that I want to display an alert.
The button becomes enabled when changing a dropdown on the page.

HTML:

```
<button id="AssignRolesButton" disabled="disabled">Assign Roles</button>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {    
    $('#AssignRolesButton').button();

    //doesnt work
    $('#AssignRolesButton').button().click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); alert('yoyo'); }); 

    $('#ApplicationsDropdownList').change(function () {  
        //enables the button 
        $('#AssignRolesButton').removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
        //doesnt work
        $('#AssignRolesButton').button().click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); alert('yoyo'); });
        // also doesnt work
        $('#AssignRolesButton').click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); alert('yoyo'); });  
   });    
});
```

So to summarise, I need the button to have the jquery ui styling while disabled and register the click function when its enabled.

Comment: You want the disabled element to fire click event or not?

Comment: @roasted: disabled elements cannot fire click events…

Comment: @Bergi ya, that's why i was asking and post as answer a workaround

Comment: missing `});` on your last click event handler and `e.preventDefault;`  should be `e.preventDefault();` - are those paste errors?

Comment: @mark yeh sorry those were paste and edit in browser errors - will edit question to fix now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> //enables the button 
> $('#AssignRolesButton').removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
> ```

No. You will need to use the [`enable` method of your Button-widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/#method-enable) ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CRa8c/)). Otherwise, the jQuery-UI-button is still disabled (even if it doesn't look like so) and jQueryUI intercepts the click event, stopping its propagation so that your handlers are not called. You can see this behavior clearly [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CRa8c/1/) - the handlers attached before jQueryUI's interceptor are still called.

> ```
> e.preventDefault;
> ```

As others mentioned, this is a *method*  and needs to be called: `e.preventDefault();`.

Comment: a problem with this solution is that every time you select something new in the dropdown another evernt handler is added. I got around this by using: `$('#AssignRolesButton').one("click", function () {
                    alert('sdsds');
                });`

Comment: That's not part of my solution, that was in your original code and I just demonstrated it now works :-) Indeed, you should attach the click handler outside of the `change` handler. Or do you expect only exactly one click per change event?

Comment: no, I ended up attaching the handler outside the change handler. Thanks for the help - its working like a charm now

Answer (score 1):

Use a workaround as disabled elements don't fire attached event:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6Kzy8/)

```
$(function () {
    var $assignBtn = $('#AssignRolesButton');
    $('<div id="btn_overlay"/>').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: $assignBtn.offset().top,
        left: $assignBtn.offset().left,
        width: $assignBtn.outerWidth(),
        height: $assignBtn.outerHeight(),
        'z-index': 1000,
    }).click(function () {
        $assignBtn.triggerHandler('click');
    }).appendTo('body');

    $('#ApplicationsDropdownList').change(function () {
        $('#btn_overlay').remove();
        $assignBtn.prop('disabled', false);
        //...
    });
    $assignBtn.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('yoyo from btn handler');
    });
});
```

Comment: Pretty much what I was thinking also. Any reason you chose `.triggerHandler` rather than `.trigger`?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss just to avoid propagation even here could not change anything

Comment: FYI, fix the e.preventDefault call - needs `()`

Comment: click the JSHint button in your demo :) find another issue. - extra comma error in IE versions. :(

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss this is not really an error, just JSHint doesn't like camel case  ;)  But, wait, i'll fix it

Answer (score 0):

Then just bind the click event, when you have selected something in the dropdown. Otherwise, leave it un-touched.